# threejs camera movement lags

Tags: three.js, camera

I'm playing around with threejs and want to create an rts game. So currently i want to create my own camera controller in order to move around the terrain. The problem is, that the movement lags, even though my fps is always between 35-50 FPS (60FPS works fine). I thought, the human eye shouldn't see something like lags with this framerate, am i wrong?

I've also calculated the movement in dependence of the delta time.

```
var translation = new Vector3();

// Move camera with keys.
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.W))
    translation.z -= (deltaTime * 200);
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.S))
    translation.z += (deltaTime * 200);
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.D))
    translation.x += (deltaTime * 200);
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A))
    translation.x -= (deltaTime * 200);

Game.Camera.position.add(translation);
```

For testing purposes (But with 60 FPS everything works fine):
http://app.lypster.net

Is it possible to solve the problem or is it a WebGL thing? I can't remember this behavior in XNA.

Kind Regards

Chris

Comment: unfortunately, your test example is not working at the moment (console says "WeakMap is not defined")

Comment: this is most likely not three.js related; the problem should be in your engine. can you come up with a raw three.js example showing the behavior?

Comment: @lot i've fixed the problem with the weakmap (I hope so, so please just retry :) )

Comment: @morris4 hmm i wonder if this is possible, since my engine isn't that much involved in this example, but i could try to create a standalone example.

Comment: Yup, it works now. But I am afraid I can't help you in any way. Your example has very little lagging. And there's too much of code to go and look for any reason for that.